# Struts 2 radio, disable specific option

Tags: radio-button, struts2, disabled-input, struts-tags

I want to disable a particular option in a radio button group with struts. 
I am able to pre-select an option using below code, can I pre-disable an option too?

```
<s:radio label="Answer" name="yourAnswer" list="#{'1':'Yes','2':'No'}" value="2">
```

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: You can use iterator.

Answer (score 1):

With iterator I got what I wanted -

```
<s:iterator value="genders" status="stat" var="gender">
    <s:if test="%{#gender == 'male'}">
        <input type="radio" name="gend" value="<s:property />" disabled="disabled">
        <s:property/>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <input type="radio" name="gend" value="%{stat+'x'}">
        <s:property/>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```